# ¿Cómo puedo validar un campo en la funcion eliminar de un CRUD con Laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel, validación

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Primero obtengo el tipo de usuario y lo guardo en la variable `$tipo`,
luego con un `if` verifico si $tipo es 1, no debe permitir eliminarlo y devolverá una vista de error con un mensaje, si `$tipo` no es 1 debe permitir eliminar usuario con el método `delete()` y retornar nuevamente a la pagina principal.

Lo he intentado de esta manera pero no ha funcionado.

Comment: antes del if haz un dd($tipo); eso parará la ejecución y verás tus datos en forma de Json, si están correctos, avisa, de lo contrario, no te está llegando bien los datos.

Comment: Estás leyendo el tipo de usuario del request, no sera que debes leerlo del usuario? Para eso lo buscas con el id no? Me resulta extraño

Comment: aplicando lo que dijo EduBw  me di cuenta de que no estaban llegando los datos y el comentario de Jakala me hizo caer en cuenta de que estaba buscando mal el tipo de usuario, aplique los cambios necesarios logre solucionarlo, de muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu método quedaría como lo siguiente:

```
public function destroy(Request $request){

$id = $request->id;
$usuario = User::find($id);

if($tipo == 1){
   return back()->withErrors('No se puede borrar al usuario administrador');
}

$usuario->delete();

return back()->with('mensaje', 'Se eliminó correctamente');

}
```

En tu vista (usando algunos estilos del framework Bootstrap):

```
@if ($errors->any())
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
                    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                    {{ $error }}
                    @endforeach
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endif
    @if (session('mensaje'))
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="alert alert-success fade in">
                    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                    {{ session('mensaje') }}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @endif
```

Comment: logre dar solución, gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta esto:

```
return back()->with('msj','No se puede borrar al usuario administrador');
```

y en vez de delete() que me imagino que sera un método tuyo, yo utilizaria destroy directamente, para no escribir aun mas código

```
User::destroy($id);
```

Ah, se me olvidaba, en la vista para poder visualizar el mensaje tendrás que declarar un `@include(flash.msg)` o algo así, si no el error no se visualiza. Si tienes dudas te lo aclaro.

Saludos. Espero te sirva.

Comment: ya logre dar solución, gracias por la ayuda.